# Creating wordpress posts into grid

Tags: css, wordpress

So I am trying to understand why my divs are not floating when requested. I am wrapping the loop of the post in a div that floats but they are just stacking as they normally would when you add a new post.

My theme is totally blank btw so there is no conflict in css.

/* My Code */

```
body{
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}



#container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    max-width: 90%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow:auto;
    height:auto;
}

.blogPost{
    float:left;
    background-color: #D9E8EC;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 300px;
}
```

this is from my index page where the posts are listing.

```
<div class="blogPost">
<?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'nav', 'below' ); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by this, do you just want to do a loop displaying posts next to each other? If so the code would be:

```
<?php
if( have_posts() ) :
    while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="blogPost">
            <?php
            get_template_part( 'entry' );
            comments_template();
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```